# Getting "The empty path didn't match any of these" error in Django urls.py file

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

[image: Project structure]

I am working on Django and I am getting error while run code like this :

```
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL

patterns, in this order:  

^admin/  
^employees/  

The empty path didn't match any of these.
```

here is my urls.py :

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from webapp import views
from django.urls import path
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns


urlpatterns = [

url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'^employees/', views.employeeList.as_view()),
]
```

here is vies.py:

```
class employeeList(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    employees1 = employees.objects.all()
    serializer = employeesSerializer(employees1, many=True)

    return Response(serializer.data)

def post(self):
    pass
```

and Settings.py :

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'rest_framework',
'webapp'
 ]
```

Comment: please post the view and the stacktrace

Comment: please check now

Comment: Empty path sounds like you aren't using /admin or /employees in the URL you are using to test Django.

Comment: can you show what url you are trying when you get the above error?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:8000/employees/

Comment: Internal Server Error: /employees/

Comment: Page not found (404)
Request Method:
GET
Request URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
^ admin/ 
^ employees/ 
The empty path didn't match any of these.

Comment: can you show your settings file and your project tree structure.

Comment: check in the image screen shot

Comment: It would be nice if you could define separate urls.py for your apps. So can you  try creating a separate url file for your webapp and declare your `employee/` urlconf in that file, and calling the app url from your main url file.

Comment: still getting error

Answer (score 0):

try changing url from

```
url(r'^employees/', views.employeeList.as_view())
```

to

```
url(r'^employees/$', views.employeeList.as_view(), name='employees' )
```

Comment: still, I am getting Error

Comment: Using the URLconf defined in mysite.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order: 
^admin/ 
^employees/$ [name='employees'] 
The empty path didn't match any of these.